# How to use RedMadRobot / input-mask-ios

Tags: ios, swift, input-mask

I have an existing project targetting iOS 12. I added pod 'InputMask' in my pod file and did an install. I now see the InputMask project in my Pods section. I select the UITextField that I want to mask but I can't see MaskedTextFieldDelegate in the custom class drop down. Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Library author here.

`MaskedTextFieldDelegate` is not a `UITextField` subclass class. You've got to drop an `NSObject` on your layout in order to see the `MaskedTextFieldDelegate` in the custom class drop down.